# Thread1: SIGABRT when using pushPaymentMethodsViewController() from Stripe

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, stripe-payments

I am trying to push the Swift PaymentMethodsViewController() from my ios app. Swift documentation recommends to do this with the following code:

```
self.paymentContext.pushPaymentMethodsViewController()
```

When I run this code I get:

```
Thread 1: signal SIGABRT
```

Usually this means that something is not set up properly in storyboard. I have tested removing the line to pushPaymentMethodsViewController() to make sure that I am not running into issues with old connections, and did not get any error, which makes me think that the problem is directly associated with the line:

```
self.paymentContext.pushPaymentMethodsViewController()
```

I am using storyboard for this application. Do I have to do any setup within storyboard to get this to work? I think my delegate functions are set up properly. Any thoughts on how to fix this? Tried cleaning and rerunning, no luck.

Here is the full output from the debugger. I did not find it to be particularly helpful, but it was requested in a comment:

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb) bt
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = signal SIGABRT
    frame #0: 0x0000000110cfbb6e libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 10
    frame #1: 0x0000000110d35080 libsystem_pthread.dylib`pthread_kill + 333
    frame #2: 0x0000000110956c97 libsystem_c.dylib`abort + 127
    frame #3: 0x00000001106e4e6f libc++abi.dylib`abort_message + 245
    frame #4: 0x00000001106e500b libc++abi.dylib`default_terminate_handler() + 265
    frame #5: 0x000000010b71f2ae libobjc.A.dylib`_objc_terminate() + 97
    frame #6: 0x00000001107020ae libc++abi.dylib`std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 8
    frame #7: 0x0000000110701d56 libc++abi.dylib`__cxa_rethrow + 99
    frame #8: 0x000000010b71f1cc libobjc.A.dylib`objc_exception_rethrow + 40
    frame #9: 0x000000010f6d3399 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 777
    frame #10: 0x00000001147baa73 GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 62
    frame #11: 0x000000010c242057 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 159
  * frame #12: 0x000000010aaa06c7 Spotbirdparking`main at AppDelegate.swift:14
    frame #13: 0x0000000110884955 libdyld.dylib`start + 1
    frame #14: 0x0000000110884955 libdyld.dylib`start + 1
(lldb)
```

Comment: DO you have an error text in debugguer/console? If yes, could you give it?

Comment: In the [example app](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ios/blob/master/Example/Standard%20Integration%20(Swift)/CheckoutViewController.swift#L157-L159) from Stripe they use a `[weak self]` with `self?`, have you tried that?

Answer (score 1):

Does the `SIGABRT` get triggered right after `pushPaymentMethodsViewController()` is called ?

If so can you check, that in your View Controller where you're calling:

`self.paymentContext.pushPaymentMethodsViewController()`

the [`hostViewController` property](https://stripe.github.io/stripe-ios/docs/Classes/STPPaymentContext.html#/c:objc(cs)STPPaymentContext(py)hostViewController) on your `paymentContext` instance is correctly set like this (right after you created your paymentContext instance):

`self.paymentContext.hostViewController = self`

If this doesn't help I suggest setting up a break point where you call `pushPaymentMethodsViewController()` and then step in the call to check exactly where this fails.